# the_post_thumbnail $size not working

Tags: php, size, thumbnails

I worked for this organization who hired a design company to design there site. We have run into a problem. The featured images are cropped. I looked at the code in post-thumbnail-template.php and it said:

```
function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
}
```

I thought that if I change the size from 'post-thumbnail' to 'full' problem would be solved but it wasn't.

So how can I add a image size that shows the image in full resolution. Do you see any errors in the code?

We have added theme support for post-thumbnails in a file (theme-init.php) that's linked to functions.php. In the same files I found this code (I didn't find any add_action add_action() for these, but when I removed them, our logo disappeared.

```
add_image_size('logo', 0, 45, false);
add_image_size('icon', 0, 51, false);
add_image_size('partner-logo', 150, 0, false);
add_image_size('long-img', 1920, 1200, false);
add_image_size('big-post', 1200, 1200, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('small-post', 1200, 1200, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('block-inf-img', 1200, 800, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('student-img', 1140, 480, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('big-post-th', 1200, 1200, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('rel-post-th', 1200, 1200, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('student-logo', 190, 0, false);
add_image_size('user_photo', 116, 116, array('center', 'center'));
```

Answer (score 1):

To use your registered image size

```
the_post_thumbnail('image-size');
```

To use the original size of an image you dont need to register image size.

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');
```

Wordpress provides predefined image sizes such as: full,thumbnail,medium,medium_large,large,1536x1536,2048x2048 .Those are the image sizes for Wordpress 5+ version for older version may varay. 
You can check how to see all image size following this link with examples - [Link](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/image-sizes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add another to your list like:

`add_image_size('full-size', 0, 0, false);`

If I recall, if you use 0, 0 it treats that as no change to the scale (I could be wrong though). `false` for the third param tells it not to do any cropping.

And then use:

`the_post_thumbnail('full-size');`

As this is a WordPress specific question I would also point you to:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What sort of image did you get back? Or nothing?

Comment: It was the same image as when I first posted cropped on all sides.

Comment: I'm curious - are you changing this `function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' )` to `function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'full-size', $attr = '' )`? Because that would be incorrect. You'd need to change it in the actual function calls. Not the definition.

Comment: I changed it to just $size = "full". Ok, what do I change it too?

Comment: Well, what you're changing is the function definition. What you need to find is the place in the template when the function is being called to display the image (it won't say function in front of it). This is where you'll need to put `the_post_thumbnail('full-size');`

Comment: And I don't see that there is any call on the function, where should I make one, in the same file as the above? And where do I change the file size to be full resolution?

Comment: It's not being called in the file I'm in

Comment: I did what you said and added the the_post_thumbnail('full-size'), but nothing changed. What can I do? Please help

Comment: I'm afraid you're changing it in the wrong place, but I don't know where you need to change it. Search your files for `the_post_thumbnail` and try to find where it is used. Sorry I can't help more than that.

Comment: Ok, I would just have to go through files until I find it... thanks for your help!

Comment: it should be in the template files, if that helps.